# RESTful web-service not found when I deploy app in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, rest, tomcat8

So, I have a Spring Maven web-app with a handful of RESTful web-services.  For testing, this project is in Spring (4.1.4.RELEASE).  I am using the latest STS (Spring-Eclipse) tool, and I am using Tomcat 8 for the server.

My UserController is designed as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    private final static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Autowired
    private IUserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ArrayList<UserEntity> getUserList()
    {
        System.out.println("UserController: getUserList: START");
        ArrayList<UserEntity> userEntityList = (ArrayList)      service.getAllUsers();
        return userEntityList;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
ArrayList<UserEntity> getAllUsers()
    {
        System.out.println("UserController: getAllUsers: START");
        ArrayList<UserEntity> userEntityList = (ArrayList)      service.getAllUsers();
        return userEntityList;
    }
```

I have a test which runs when I build the app with maven, and this works great:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
```

{ "classpath:/spring/angular-context.xml", "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml" })
    @Transactional
    public class BaseControllerTests extends TestCase {

```
@Test
public void testMockGetUserList1() throws Exception
{
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users/");
        this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

@Test
public void testMockGetUserList2() throws Exception
{
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users");
        this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}
```

The web-xml file looks like:

```
<web-app>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/spring/angular-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/logging/log4j-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jUnitHostImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jUnitHostImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SoccerApp/junithost/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And the angular-context.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tomholmes.angularjs.phonebook" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phonebook</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>myusername</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>mypassword</value>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- JNDI DataSource for Java EE environments -->
<!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatabase"/> -->


<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tomholmes.angularjs.phonebook.domain" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="mail.tomholmes.net" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />

    <property name="username" value="myusername" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--  
<bean id="sendMailService" class="com.tomholmes.angularjs.phonebook.shared.util.SendEmailService">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
-->

<bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

So, this project compiles under maven just fine.   Under eclipse (STS) with the Tomcat 8 engine, it runs fine, and I can go to my app:
  http://localhost:8080/angularjs-phone-book/
and I can see the index.html just fine, so I know the app is out there.

If I go to:

```
 http://localhost:8080/angularjs-phone-book/users
 http://localhost:8080/angularjs-phone-book/users/
 http://localhost:8080/angularjs-phone-book/rest/users
 http://localhost:8080/angularjs-phone-book/rest/users/
```

Nothing works, and I get a 404 error that this web-service is not found.
But like I said, I know the test works, but I can't see what the exact URL has to be to get there.

I tried deploying the WAR on Tomcat 8 directly, but this web-app won't even start there, supposedly because of logging problems.

If I can provide any more information, please let me know.  Any help in finding this would be great.  Ultimately I want to have an AngularJS UI on the front-end tied to web-services, and I have to get the web-services working first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss the Spring config reference from your web.xml. The unit test runs because you give the reference to the XML directly there, but not in web.xml, so Spring will not scan your controller for annotations.

Use an `<init-param>` inside `<servlet>`!

And the correct URL will be the last one, that is, with .../rest/users/, and .../rest/users is also allowed by the help of the browser, I guess.